# VS 2022 not displaying design time errors in .NET site

Tags: .net, syntax-error, design-time, visual-studio-2022

I've been using VS 2022 for the past month and a week ago it suddenly stopped error checking during design time in my .NET website.
It was working and I cannot figure out why it stopped.
I reset all of the settings, I uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studios.
I created a new empty .NET site and it's still not checking errors in .vb files or in server script tags.
What could be the cause of this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure of the cause, but I was also seeing this issue on VS 17.0.0. After upgrading to 17.0.2 I'm seeing the inline errors again.